# Strenght-gain period in fullbody workout way

Tags: exercise, strength-training, overtraining, interval-training

Well, last month I started to feel really tired after my gym sessions and, what most important here, my weights are not growing up anymore.

As a matter of fact I being doing full body workout during almost last 2 years  (ofc I got some week or two breaks, even month two times because of traumas/being sick, also stopped to do legs this summer because of varicose)

I've been doing it like 3 times per week, something like this now:

**Session 1:**

- Pull-ups (with extra weight 5kg), 3-4 * 8-10
- T-bar row, 3-4, 8-12, 30 kg
- Incline barbells press 3-4, 22kg * 8-10
- Kneeling cable crunches,    3-4, 16-20 reps
- Biceps & triceps stuff

**Session 2:**

- Incline bench press, 3-4, 57.5kg *6-10
- Pull-ups (with extra weight, 10kg), 3-4 * 8
- Standing lat pushdown, 3-4, 10-12
- Biceps & triceps stuff

**Session 3:**

- Pull-ups (no weight), 3-4 * 12
- Seated cable row, 4*12
- Incline barbell press, 16kg, 3-4, 10
- Leg raises to the bar (abs exercise), 3-4,  8-12
- Biceps & triceps stuff

So, regarding to this information, how should I set sort of a strange gain program in terms of fullbody workout?

P.S.

I'm 24yo, 182cm, 75kg

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "strange gain program"? Do you mean "strength"? 2) Your full body routine appears to be missing half the body (no lower body exercises)

Comment: @DarkHippo 1) oh my, sorry for mispelling word "strength" 2) yeah since my varicose vains start to hurt sometimes I decided to don't do any squats and legpresses I usually being doing, so (I mentioned this in the question body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very good that you do a full body workout, I am doing that and it works well.

To maximize each workout, especially if someone have been doing this for a while and the body is somewhat used to the routine, you need to train every other day.

This give you plenty of time to recover, which is needed, as you grow when you rest and sleep, especially for people that train naturally, with no added chemicals.

The days you train, you need to maximize the exercises to the maximum weight that allows you to do between 6 and 8 reps, for a maximum of 5 sets per exercise, and you should do no more then 2 exercises per body part.

This mean that you need to choose the exercises that maximise growth, at this stage, and not concentration exercises that defines.

For example for chest you should use bench press and dips or flys, if you are on your own with no one to spot you, you can use the smith machine for security and to help to keep a stricter form.

T-bar for the back and pulls up or lat pull down are good.

Military press for the shoulder front and back with smith machine or bar, or with dumbells is good.

Triceps pulldown or extensions with tricep dips on a superset basis with biceps barbell curl and dumbbell screw curls, keeps the blood in the same area and maximise pump.

Legs you do last, as they would take up a lot of energy at the beginning, if you can use a leg press or smith machine for squat is better, no need for leg extension at the moment.

If you maintain a resting time between sets of about 30 seconds, you will be keeping the right intensity that stimulate growth and maximise growth hormone secretion.

At this pace you should be able to do all of the body in about 1 hour, off course you will not have time to chat or looking at your mobile!

To go with this, it is important that you look after your diet, but this is another subject, which to comment on, I would need to know when you train and what you do on a daily basis.

Hope this help, but if you put this into practice, after only 2 weeks you will notice a different on the pump and other markers.

Comment: wellp, being doing stuff like this for 3 weeks, and now I'm back at my previous routine plan. What I can say - it worked. 
Now my incline bench press weight is 60 kilos, and I do 3*10 of pull ups with 10 kilos on me.
Also, there are some gains in biceps curl and triceps. Maybe it seems not sufficent but I was trying to break this level since the beggining of summer without any success

Answer (score 1):

there are a few points to be answered on your comments above.

I will ty to answer one by one over a period of time.

The first point is about the calories intake and % of what you eat.

First of all I should ask how old you are and how much you weight, however, given the calories you tell me you consume, I can tell you that they are way too much, you do not need so many calories, especially if a lot of them comes from proteins and carbs.

To build muscles, you do not need a lot of protein, that is old school, the most recent research shows that 1g per pound of body weight would be enough. 
At the moment you are telling me that you are consuming 3000 calories of which 40% protein which equal 1200 calories, which divided by 4, the calories per grams of protein, you are eating 300 grams of protein. When you eat too much protein, the body uses some, and then some will be converted into glucose and the insulin will convert the rest into fat.

It is an expensive way to get glucose!

That amount of protein will also create other demands on the digestive system, insulin resistance, amount of vitamins and enzimes to absorb them, etc.., too long to discuss now.

That it is about the proteins.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Well, I'm 24 years old, 75 kilos now. Well I yet got no problems with fat currently (but when I stop to walking 6 miles per day and stop my gym sessions even when I cut during this period I gain some fat, thats strange)

Comment: Wellp, about glucose it seems like kinda hard to kick this process to start even above 2gramss per kilo https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4258944/

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4022420/ and look at this

Comment: Oh andthe most thing, I am really sorry, I noticed it only now, my comment is really confused you, and I realize why now - by 30-40% protein and stuff I mean like protein" based" food like boiled chicken or crud (ofc some whey powder, around 50/100 gramms per day/training day) etc

Answer (score 1):

To just clarify the weight gaining side when you stop walking and gym, I can say that I am not surprised and it is not strange, given the amount of carbohydrate you take in and proteins.

The body receives all of that and it will spike your insulin very high, the presence of insulin in the bloodstream will reduce glucose but will also open the cells and let in the fat along with the rest.

Insulin does not take fat and store them as fat, insulin take carbohydrate and excess glucose from proteins and stores them as fat, fat spike insulin only on an insignificant way, fat it is not your problem.

Your exercise just about keep you from gaining weight.

Comment: yep, I guess its the problem

Answer (score 0):

In one of you point, you mentioned varicose veins.

Over many years in the gym, I have seen many people having issues with varicose or spider veins.

The only thing that seemed to work, regardless of what their doctor told them is exercise, which you already do, and a constant long term use of vitamin C.

Make sure that you do not buy any supplement that have a large amount of "ascorbic acid", because that it is not really vitamin C, it is just a small component and not the best component, it is just the outer layer of the vitamin.

The best foods with the highest content to consume for vitamin C are Kiwi, Papaya and Peppers, Peppers are better if you do not want to eat too much sugars coming from the fruit.